# Update functionality in React - Fetch values and populate onto input boxes

Tags: reactjs

I am a newbie to react and I am trying to fetch data and to populate those values onto the input boxes but I couldn't. I don't understand the error.

My code and screenshot is below.

**UpdateLevel.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Sidebar from '../Sidebar';
import JobService from "../../Services/JobService";
// import '../css/Create.css';
import './../Job/Job.css';
// import '../../Job.css';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
class UpdateLevel extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
super(props)
this.state={
id:0,
level:'',
levelDes:'',
errors:{}   
}
this.id=this.id.bind(this);
this.level=this.level.bind(this);
this.levelDes=this.levelDes.bind(this);
this.UpdateInterviewLevel=this.UpdateInterviewLevel.bind(this);
this.cancel=this.cancel.bind(this);
}    
componentDidMount(){
console.log(this.props.match);
JobService.GetInterviewLevelById(localStorage.getItem('id')).then((res)=>{
let level=res.data;
this.setState({
id:localStorage.getItem('id')
,level: level.level,
levelDes:level.levelDes
});
});
}
UpdateInterviewLevel=(e)=>{
e.preventDefault();
let errors={};
// var pattern=new RegExp( /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{4,16}$/);
// var patt=new RegExp(/\d$/);        
let formvalidstatus=true;  
if(this.state.level==""){
formvalidstatus=false;
errors["level"]="Please enter Level !";
}       
if((this.state.levelDes)==""){
formvalidstatus=false;
errors["levelDes"]="Please enter Description!";
} 
this.setState({
errors:errors
});
if(formvalidstatus==true){
let lev={id:parseInt(this.state.id),
level:this.state.level,
levelDes:this.state.levelDes,
};
console.log('lev=>'+lev.level+ " " + lev.levelDes
);
console.log('lev=>'+JSON.stringify(lev));
JobService.UpdateInterviewLevel(lev.id,lev).then(res=>{
window.location="/viewlevel";
localStorage.setItem('Updatestatus',true);
alert('Interview Level Updated successfully')
});
}
}
id(event){
this.setState({id:event.target.value});
} 
level(event){
this.setState({level:event.target.value});
}
levelDes(event){
this.setState({levelDes:event.target.value});
}
cancel(){
alert( window.location.replace('http://localhost:3000/'))
}
render(){
// console.log(this.props.match.params);
return(
<div>
   <div class="side">
      <Sidebar />
   </div>
   <form className="addformjob">
      <h2><strong>Update Interview Level</strong></h2>
      <label>Id</label>
      <input id="id"  name="id" value={ this.state.id} onChange={this.id}></input><br></br>
      {/* 
      <div className="errorMsgJob">{this.state.errors.id}</div>
      */}
      <label>Level</label>
      <input id="level" type="text" name="level"  value={ this.state.level} onChange={this.level}></input><br></br>
      <div className="errorMsgJob">{this.state.errors.level}</div>
      <br></br>
      <label >Description</label>
      <input  id="levelDes" type="text"  name="levelDes" value={ this.state.levelDes} onChange={this.levelDes}></input><br></br>
      <div className="errorMsgJob">{this.state.errors.levelDes}</div>
      <br></br>
      <br></br>
      <button id="jobb" className="btn btn-success" onClick={(e)=>this.UpdateInterviewLevel(e)}>Update</button>
      <br></br>
      <br></br>
      <Link to={'/viewlevel'}>
      <button className="btn btn-outline-dark" type="submit" onClick={()=>{window.location='/viewlevel'}}>Back</button>
      </Link> 
      <br></br>
   </form>
</div>
)
}
}
export default UpdateLevel
```

**JobService.js**

```
import axios from "axios";
const Job_Baseurl="https://localhost:44348/api/Jobs";
class JobService{
GetAllJobs(){
return axios.get(Job_Baseurl+"/GetAllJobs");
}
Addjob(job){
return axios.post(Job_Baseurl+"/AddJob",job);
}
GetJobById(id){
return axios.get(Job_Baseurl+"/GetJobById?id="+id);
}
UpdateJob(id, job){
return axios.put(Job_Baseurl+"/UpdateJob?id="+id,job);
}
DeleteJob(id)
{
return axios.delete(Job_Baseurl+"/DeleteJob?id="+id);
}
AddInterview(job){
return axios.post(Job_Baseurl+"/AddInterviewLevel",job);
}
GetInterviewLevelById(id){
return axios.get(Job_Baseurl+"/GetInterviewLevelById?id="+id);
}
UpdateInterviewLevel(id,level){
return axios.put(Job_Baseurl+"/UpdateInterviewLevel?id="+id,level);
}
GetAllInterviewLevels(){
return axios.get(Job_Baseurl+"/GetAllInterviewLevels");
}
DeleteInterviewLevel(id)
{
return axios.delete(Job_Baseurl+"/DeleteInterviewLevel?id="+id);
}
}
export default new JobService()
```

**ViewLevel.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Sidebar from '../Sidebar';
import JobService from "../../Services/JobService";
import '../css/View.css';
import {toast} from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { confirmAlert } from 'react-confirm-alert'; // Import
import 'react-confirm-alert/src/react-confirm-alert.css'; // Import css
class ViewLevel extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
super(props)
this.state={
levels:[],
currentPage:1,
jobsPerPage:5
}
this.addLevel=this.addLevel.bind(this);
this.editLevel=this.editLevel.bind(this);
this.deleteLevel=this.deleteLevel.bind(this);
this.deleteButton=this.deleteButton.bind(this);
this.searchItems=this.searchItems.bind(this);
}
deleteButton(id)
{
confirmAlert({
title:'Delete Confirmation',
message:'Are you sure you want to delete this ?',
buttons:[
{
label:'Delete',
className:'but1',
onClick:()=> this.deleteLevel(id)
},
{
label:'Cancel',
onClick:()=>window.location='/viewlevel'
}
]
});
}
deleteLevel(id){
JobService.DeleteInterviewLevel(id).then(res=>{
this.setState({levels:this.state.levels.filter(level=>level.id!==id)});
});
window.location='/viewlevel';
localStorage.setItem('Deletestatus',true);
}
editLevel(id){
localStorage.setItem('userid',id);
window.location=`/updatelevel/${id}`;
}
addLevel(){
window.location="/interview";
}
displayToast=()=>{
if(localStorage.getItem('Deletestatus'))  {
toast('Deleted Successfully',{
position:toast.POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER,
type:toast.TYPE.SUCCESS,
toastId:'del'
})      
}
if(localStorage.getItem('Resgisterstatus'))  {
toast('Added Successfully',{
position:toast.POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER,
type:toast.TYPE.SUCCESS,
toastId:'add',
})      
}
if(localStorage.getItem('Updatestatus'))  {
toast('Updated Successfully ',{
position:toast.POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER,
type:toast.TYPE.SUCCESS,
toastId:'update',
})      
}
}
clearData=()=>{
localStorage.removeItem('Resgisterstatus');
localStorage.removeItem('Deletestatus');
localStorage.removeItem('Updatestatus');
}
componentDidMount(){
JobService.GetAllInterviewLevels().then((res)=>{
this.setState({levels:res.data});
this.displayToast(); 
this.clearData();
});
}
searchItems=(event)=>{
let searchval=event.target.value.toLowerCase();
let res=this.state.levels.filter(level=>{ 
return(((level.id.toString()).indexOf(searchval)!==-1)||
((level.level.toLowerCase()).indexOf(searchval)!==-1)||
((level.levelDes.toLowerCase()).indexOf(searchval)!==-1))
})
if(res==""||searchval==""){
if(res==""){
toast("Searched value not found",
{
position:toast.POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER,
type: toast.TYPE.WARNING,
toastId:'search',
autoClose:1000,
onClose:function(){
window.location.reload();
}
})
}
else{
window.location.reload();
}
}
else{
this.setState({
levels:res
})
}
}
render(){
const indexOfLastEmpolyee=this.state.currentPage * this.state.jobsPerPage;
const indexOfFirstEmployee=indexOfLastEmpolyee-this.state.jobsPerPage;
const currentEmployees=this.state.levels.slice(indexOfFirstEmployee,indexOfLastEmpolyee);
const pageNumbers=[];
for(let i=1;i<=Math.ceil(this.state.levels.length/this.state.jobsPerPage);i++){
pageNumbers.push(i);
}
const setPage=(pageNum)=>{
this.setState({currentPage:pageNum})
}
return(
<div className="container">
   <div class="side">
      <Sidebar />
   </div>
   <div className="addbtn">
      {/* <button className="add" onClick={this.addJob}>Add Job</button> */}
      <button className="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit" onClick={()=>{window.location='/interview'}}>Add Interview Level</button>
   </div>
   {/* 
   <div className="searchbtn">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search here" onChange={(e)=>this.searchItems(e)}/>
   </div>
   */}
   .
   <br></br>
   <br></br>
   <br></br>
   <h3>Interview Level Details</h3>
   <br></br>
   <table className="table">
      <thead className="dark">
         <tr>
            <th>Level</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         {
         currentEmployees.map(items=>(
         <tr key={items.id}>
            <td>{items.level}</td>
            <td>{items.levelDes}</td>
            <td><button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={()=>this.editLevel(items.id)}>Edit</button></td>
            <td><button className="btn btn-danger"  onClick={()=>this.deleteButton(items.id)}>Delete</button></td>
         </tr>
         ))}
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <div className="pagination">
      {
      pageNumbers.map((pageNum,index)=>(
      <span key={index}   onClick={()=>{setPage(pageNum)}}>
      {pageNum}
      </span>
      ))
      }
   </div>
</div>
)
}
}
export default ViewLevel
```

When I am clicking the edit button in ViewLevel.js the values doesn't get populated onto the input boxes and I am getting an error like this in console:

> GET https://localhost:44348/api/Jobs/GetInterviewLevelById?id=null 404
> Uncaught (in promise) AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404', name:
> 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
> code: "ERR_BAD_REQUEST"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This error has nothing to do with React itself. You're making a GET request to the server with an invalid URL. The server responds with a 404 status code. Your server does not accept this URL `https://localhost:44348/api/Jobs/GetInterviewLevelById?id=null`

Comment: Thank You for responding. But the URL is valid.

Comment: Can you provide more information about the server route? Which parameters does it accept? Does it accept id=null? Because, as Axios tells us, you're performing a bad request.

Comment: Server route doesn't accept id=null. Here I am sharing my github link to API Project for your reference.                                             
https://github.com/Jeevithasri17/DotnetAPI-InterviewScheduler

Comment: Then I would suggest adding a condition to only perform your request if you have a valid instead of NULL.